# Why does this code snippet only show 2 posts when I am pushing a third into the array?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions.
The first one (`getPosts`), accesses an array of objects (called `posts`) and "shows" them at the webpage after some delay, using setTimeout.
The second one (`createPost`), takes one object as argument (a `post`) and push it at the end of the posts array.
Code follows:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
]

function getPosts(){
    posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.body.innerHTML += post.body+'<br>';
        },3000);
    })
}

function createPost(post){
        posts.push(post);
}

getPosts();
//third post added here but does not show?
createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

My question is why getPosts doesn't show the third post at the webpage although is executed after 3 seconds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you *call* `getPosts` the array only has *two* items, so it delays *two* functions that will show a post.

Comment: Look at your code in `getPosts`.  You execute this immediately, iterating through each `post` in `posts` _straight away_.  The three-second delay is on adding the new post to the body.  However, when this code executes there are only 2 posts

Comment: You are getting your posts first (two of them) after that you are adding in the event loop a timeout to updated the innerHTML of an element after 3 seconds, meanwhile you updated the posts list with a third post. After 3 seconds, the list with the 2 elements is displayed, there is no other call to get the updated list after your post. You need to do createPost and after that get the posts again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to showcase it is by showing what `getPosts` actually does with a small `console.log`:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
]

function getPosts(){
    posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
        console.log(`item ${index} with content "${post.body}". Showing delayed for later.`)
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.body.innerHTML += post.body+'<br>';
        },3000);
    })
}

function createPost(post){
        posts.push(post);
}

getPosts();
//third post added here but does not show?
createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

At the time your `getPosts` executes, there are only **two** items in the array, so

1. It goes over each
2. Delays the showing of it for later
3. Stops

It will never check if the array has more items at a later point of time, since it has stopped executing.

If you do want to print all the contents after 3 seconds, then you can wrap the entire body in `setTimeout`:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
]

function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(()=>{//<-- delay the entire function body
        posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
                document.body.innerHTML += post.body+'<br>';
        })
    },3000);//<--
}

function createPost(post){
        posts.push(post);
}

getPosts();
//third post added and shown later
createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

Or perhaps even simpler to just delay the execution, instead of having that logic inside the function:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
]

function getPosts(){
    posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
        document.body.innerHTML += post.body+'<br>';
    })
}

function createPost(post){
        posts.push(post);
}

setTimeout(getPosts, 3000); //delay here

createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time VLAZ. Your answer was really helpful. The thing that confused me at last, was the first parameter in `foreach` method. Thanks again. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`posts.forEach` is executed before the timer, when there were only 2 entries

```
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
];

function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        posts.forEach((post, index, arr) => {
            console.log(post.body + '<br>');
        }, 3000);
    })

    // posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
    //     setTimeout(()=>{
    //         console.log(post.body+'<br>');
    //     },3000);
    // })
}

function createPost(post){
    posts.push(post);
}

getPosts();
createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead putting timeout inside loop, if you put loop inside timeout then you will get what you are expecting:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
];

function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        posts.forEach((post, index, arr) => {
            console.log(post.body + '<br>');
        });
    }, 3000);
}

function createPost(post){
    posts.push(post);
}

getPosts();
createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why getPosts doesn't show the third post at the webpage although is executed after 3 seconds?

The `getPosts` doesn't execute after 3 seconds, only the two items are displayed with a delay of 3 seconds, instead you could delay the execution of `getPosts` and you'll get the expected result:

```js
const posts = [
    {title: "#1", body: "This is post number one"},
    {title: "#2", body: "This is another post (#2)"}
]

function getPosts(){
    posts.forEach((post,index,arr)=>{
      document.body.innerHTML += post.body+'<br>';     
    })
}

function createPost(post){
        posts.push(post);
}

setTimeout(getPosts, 3000);

createPost({title:'henlo',body:'troll message'});
```